# Conservateur ou conservatiste ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Quelle est la différence entre *conservateur* et *conservatiste* ?

Conservatiste est un [nom](http://www.littre.org/definition/conservatiste) et conservateur est un adjectif, mais il me semble qu'on utilise souvent conservateur en tant que nom comme dans « Ce conservateur est une figure montante ».

Y a-t-il une subtilité que je ne saisis pas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Conservateur** est nom et adjectif. Il a toujours été nom et adjectif depuis qu'il est apparu dans la langue française (13<sup>e</sup>siècle). [Voir le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/conservateur) par exemple, confirmé par le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*<sup>1</sup>.

Le nom **conservatiste**<sup>2</sup>, apparu au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle, est signalé par très peu de dictionnaires, le TLF ne le connait pas et le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*<sup>1</sup> signale qu'il n'a jamais réussi à s'imposer face à conservateur.

Un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conservatiste%2C%20conservateur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconservatiste%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconservateur%3B%2Cc0) est très révélateur sur la fréquence d'emploi respective des deux mots, même si le ngram ne permet pas de distinguer la nature des mots.

En approfondissant la recherche à partir de ce ngram on voit que parmi les rares occurrences de « conservatiste », l'emploi comme adjectif est plus fréquent dans les années récentes, mais ça reste de toute façon très marginal.

<sup>1 sld Alain Rey, édition 1998.</sup> 
<sup>2 Quand il est donné par les dictionnaires il est donné uniquement comme nom.  La recherche google montre que certains auteurs l'ont utilisé comme adjectif mais cet emploi reste marginal</sup>

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas Ngram, mias effectivement c'est très révélateur. Merci Laure pour cette réponse détaillée !

Answer (score 1):

Je ne crois pas qu'il y'ait un seul exemple dans la littérature courante d'usage de "conservatiste" qui n'est tout simplement pas un mot utilisé en français. En revanche, le "conservatisme", attitude des conservateurs, est un substantif courant.